# How exactly is an SLD_body object (when extracted from its XML href) structured when using a cElementTree to parse it?

Tags: geoserver, development, database, xml, datastructure

I'm trying to export data from a PostGIS database into a geoserver and I've gotten it to where I can get the PostGIS database to point to the geoserver (I'm doing this as a python script for a GIS program) with gsconfig. So essentially I need to establish the services so that I can see the data in the geoserver data store/namespace that I have created. Therefore I'm using the xml.etree from cElementTree package in Python to parse the data from my database using gsconfig's catalog object. However, I don't know that much about XML and how its structured, but I have the gist of the element tree structure.